# How to make a method wait for an AJAX call to return a result before it returning its own result?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest, synchronous

I can't get through this. Every thread I read about this problem leads me to failure, so I'll try again in this thread.

I need to make an AJAX call in a method. My function needs to wait for my ajax result before returning anything.

I read that Deferred should be the right way to do it, but it does not work.

```
my_method();

function my_method() {
  var d1 = $.Deferred();
  console.log('Start');
  $.when(d1).done(function(value) {
    console.log(value);
  });

  $.ajax({
    url: '/echo/js/?js=hello%20world',
    complete: function(response) {
      d1.resolve("Done");
    }
  });
  console.log('End method');
}

console.log('Outside World');
```

SAMPLE JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/ttx1qp0r/

As you can see this code outputs in order:
 -Start
 -End method
 -Outside World
 -Done

But this is not what I want. I need Outside World to be the last thing happening.

Technically, I'm trying to make a synchronous ajax call but using async: false is deprecated or not a good idea (not futureproof).

What am I doing wrong? The flow of my application relies on this.

Thanks

Comment: You're right - you're trying to make a synchronous ajax call but using async: false is deprecated or not a good idea. You have to change the outside world to make it wait until after your code.

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping your outside world in a function and then calling that function after `done` like:

```
my_method();

function my_method() {
  var d1 = $.Deferred();
  console.log('Start');
  $.when(d1).done(function(value) {
    console.log(value);
    outsideWorld();
  });

  $.ajax({
    url: '/echo/js/?js=hello%20world',
    complete: function(response) {
      d1.resolve("Done");
    }
  });
  console.log('End method');
}

function outsideWorld()
{
    console.log('Outside World');
}
```

Comment: i don't have any access to the code "Outside world". Imagine a whole page where my JS gets injected at some point and i can only manage one function called from the page. My function needs to finish before letting the rest of the world run.